# Query converting number into digits fails

Tags: prolog

```
split(0).
split(M,List) :-
    M > 0,
    MM is floor(M / 10),
    Z is M mod 10,
    append(List,[Z],SubList),
    nl,
    print(SubList),
    split(MM,SubList).
```

Comment: What do you mean with *return false*? You did not provide a query.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a simple typo: your `split/1` fact has arity one whereas your inductive case has arity two. Modifying your first line to:

```
split(0,[]).
```

and you should use `append/3` the opposite way:

```
append(SubList,[Z],List),
```

so the predicate is like:

```
split(0,[]).
split(M,List) :-
    M > 0,
    MM is floor(M / 10),
    Z is M mod 10,
    append(SubList,[Z],List),
    split(MM,SubList).
```

Will solve the problem *partly*: it will return one correct answer. But then get stuck into an infinite loop. The reason is that you call `append/3` with both `List` and `SubList` uninstantiated, so like:

```
append(A,[3],B).
```

Running this into the runtime environment generates:

```
?- append(A,[3],B).
A = [],
B = [3] ;
A = [_G218718],
B = [_G218718, 3] ;
A = [_G218718, _G218724],
B = [_G218718, _G218724, 3] ;
A = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730],
B = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730, 3] ;
A = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730, _G218736],
B = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730, _G218736, 3] ;
A = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730, _G218736, _G218742],
B = [_G218718, _G218724, _G218730, _G218736, _G218742, 3];
```

(etc.)

So there is an infinite amount of lists for which the `append/3` predicate succeeds, and all these lists will fail, because eventually you call `split/2` with `0` requires an empty list, and that's not the case.

## More elegant solution with accumulator

Using `append/3` with one element is in general not very efficient: it results in *O(n)* time complexity per insertion, thus for this problem your `split/2` predicate will run in O(n<sup>2</sup>). A solution is to use an accumulator: a variable you update through the recursive calls. In that case your first predicate links `split/2` with `split/3`: a version with an accumulator.

```
split(A,B) :-
    split(A,[],B).
```

Now the inductive case of `split/3` is again the one where `A == 0`. In that case we see the accumulator as the final result:

```
split(0,B,B).
```

The inductive case means that we look for the digit, add it at the head of the accumulator, and pass it recursively:

```
split(M,Acc,Res) :-
    M > 0,
    MM is floor(M / 10),
    Z is M mod 10,
    split(MM,[Z|Acc],Res).
```

So putting it all together, our version has the following code:

```
split(A,B) :-
    split(A,[],B).

split(0,B,B).
split(M,Acc,Res) :-
    M > 0,
    MM is floor(M / 10),
    Z is M mod 10,
    split(MM,[Z|Acc],Res).
```

Comment: @HanaaAldaly: furthermore the police on SO is one question per ...well... *question*. So consider opening a new question.